# How to get store value from Sencha extjs

Tags: json, extjs, store, extjs6-modern

I want to retrieve all datas from store for doing some validations in sencha extjs6. I have a model, a store, and one json file. But I don't know how to get the store value from json. For example, store the value from store to an variable or array for my further validation. Please kindly help me on this since I am new to sencha extjs. 
Here is my codes:

**Model**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.MobilePrefix', {

extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

config: {

    fields: [
        {name: 'id', type: 'int'},
        {name: 'prefix', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'length', type: 'int'}
    ]   
}
});
```

**Store**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.MobilePrefix', {

extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

requires: [
    'MyApp.model.MobilePrefix'
],

config: {
    model: 'MyApp.model.MobilePrefix',

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
         url: 'resources/data/MobilePrefix.json',


        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'MobilePrefix'
        }
    },

    autoLoad: true
}

});
```

**Json**
*MobilePrefix.json*

```
{
"MobilePrefix": [
    {"id": 1, "prefix":"012", "length":6 },
    {"id": 2, "prefix":"015", "length":6 },
    {"id": 3, "prefix":"097", "length":7 }
   ]
}
```

---

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where you have to add validation, fetch data with Ext.getStore('MobilePrefix').data , and then add your validation code.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

Use listeners in you Store file.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.MobilePrefix', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
requires: ['MyApp.model.MobilePrefix'],
autoLoad: true,
config: {
    model: 'MyApp.model.MobilePrefix',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'resources/data/MobilePrefix.json',


        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'MobilePrefix'
        }
    },
    listeners: {
        load: function(store) {
            console.log(store.data);
        }

    }
}
});
```